# "Unable to download the software from the server at this time error" when installing printer

Tags: printing, driver, canon

I keep getting the following message (see image below) when trying to install a shared printer, I first got this error a month ago and have been trying every couple of days since, but i guess the error is permanent rather than a glitch.

Any ideas how i could resolve this ?

[image: error message]

Comment: Does the error persist past a day or a week? Please add some details if this wasn't just a temporary error with the site serving the updates..

Answer (score 1):

Normally your Apple would automatically download the supported printer drivers with system software.

Run a Software update (Click on Apple icon top left) on you computer to get a update.

OR-->

Download the driver from here:

http://www.techspot.com/drivers/driver/file/information/16150/

> Apple delivers third-pary software for scanners and printers via
>   Software Update. Simply connect the printer or scanner to the Mac. If
>   software is needed and available, OS X will automatically download and
>   install it.
>
> This article is a comprehensive list of currently supported printer
>   and scanner models and associated software provided by third-party
>   vendors as of 28 June 2012.
>
> Important: Run Software Update before connecting to a printer or
>   scanner. This will update the Mac's database on the latest supported
>   printer and scanner models.